# How to apply pivot in visualisation in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have 4 columns in my table Alarm_type(string), End_date(date), Staus(string), Start_date(date). as you can see on screenshot
[image]

| Alarm_type | start_date | End_date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IFP mismatch | 12/12/12 | 01/01/13 | Close |
| IFP Value | 02/03/09 | 04/04/12 | Open |

I want a seperate column for Open and close from status column. I don't want to change my table. I have checked through matrix but from Matrix i am not able to achieve that

Expected

| Alarm_type | start_date | End_date | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IFP mismatch | 12/12/12 | 01/01/13 | null | close |
| IFP Value | 02/03/09 | 04/04/12 | Open | null |

Comment: Can you update your question with a snip of a mock up of what you'd like your matrix to be.

Comment: I have updated my question pls have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the following Matrix without any modification or addition to your data model. You can't edit the column labels or ordering in this approach.

[image]

Format visual properties:

- Row headers >  - +/- icons Off
- Row headers > Options > Stepped layout Off

---

Alternatively, you can create two measures with:

```
a = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[Status]) = "Open", "Open")

b = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[Status]) = "Close", "Close")
```

And then use these in your Matrix Values well, with the Columns well empty.
[image]

Or use the Table visual with the same.
[image]